# How to create parameterized queries with excel ? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm trying to use parameterized queries to run faster update clauses in an Excel sheet... but when trying to do , vb.net says "Operation must use an updateable query".

With regular queries with concatenations , the query works:

```
 Protected Friend Sub reemplazarDato(ByVal columna As String, ByVal dato As String, ByVal con As String)
    Dim cmd As String = ""
    conexion.Open()
    For Each itm In arrayErrores
        cmd = "UPDATE [" & obtenerHojaActual(columna, con) & "$] SET [" & columna & "]='" & dato & "' WHERE [" & columna & "]='" & itm & "'"
        Try
            Dim comando As New OleDbCommand(cmd, conexion)
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
            comando.Dispose()               
        Catch ex As Exception
            repairmanMessage("Error inesperado", ex.Message, My.Resources._error).ShowDialog()
        End Try
    Next
    conexion.Close()
End Sub
```

But when I try this way, the query dont work... ("Operation must use an updateable query")

```
Protected Friend Sub reemplazarDato(ByVal columna As String, ByVal dato As String, ByVal con As String)
    Dim cmd As String = ""
    Dim hoja As String = obtenerHojaActual(columna, con)
    Dim comando As New OleDbCommand
    comando.Connection = conexion
    conexion.Open()
    For Each itm In arrayErrores
        cmd = "UPDATE [" & hoja & "$] SET [@columna]=@dato WHERE [@columna]=@itm"
        comando.CommandText = cmd
        comando.Parameters.Add("@columna", OleDbType.VarChar, columna.Length).Value = columna
        comando.Parameters.Add("@dato", OleDbType.VarChar, dato.Length).Value = dato
        comando.Parameters.Add("@itm", OleDbType.VarChar, itm.ToString.Length).Value = itm
        Try
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
            comando.Parameters.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            repairmanMessage("Error inesperado", ex.Message, My.Resources._error).ShowDialog()
        End Try
    Next
    conexion.Close()
    comando.Dispose()
End Sub
```

how can I do this with excel?

Comment: I don't believe that it is valid to parameterize column names in SQL - i.e. `columna` needs to be set using string concatenation as in your first code block, and not as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks mark, that was the problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not valid to parameterize the column name - i.e. `columna` needs to be set using string concatenation as in your first code block, and not as a parameter.  Also, you don't need to define the SQL and command parameters for each iteration - just define them once and set the value each time around the loop.

```
Protected Friend Sub reemplazarDato(ByVal columna As String, ByVal dato As String, ByVal con As String)
    Dim hoja As String = obtenerHojaActual(columna, con)
    Dim comando As New OleDbCommand
    comando.Connection = conexion
    comando.CommandText = "UPDATE [" & hoja & "$] SET [" & columna & "]=@dato WHERE [" & columna & "]=@itm"
    comando.Parameters.Add("@dato", OleDbType.VarChar, dato.Length)
    comando.Parameters.Add("@itm", OleDbType.VarChar, itm.ToString.Length)
    conexion.Open()
    For Each itm In arrayErrores
        comando.Parameters("@dato").Value = dato
        comando.Parameters("@itm").Value = itm
        Try
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            repairmanMessage("Error inesperado", ex.Message, My.Resources._error).ShowDialog()
        End Try
    Next
    conexion.Close()
    comando.Dispose()
End Sub
```